# Creating data frame from one column

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot, multiple-columns, rows

I have the following table consisting of one column with same feature names, but different values:

[image]

and I would like to convert it into multiple columns data frame driven by feature names- like that:

[image]

The examples I have have found does not resolve my issue. I think that pivot would be helpful here. I thought about using the below example, however I have only one column which is my index at the same time and lost the concept. Any clue would be much appreciated.

t = df.pivot_table(index='A',values=0,aggfunc=list).squeeze()
out = pd.DataFrame(t.tolist(),index=t.index)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice, rather improve the other one

Comment: Well, it seems that addressing questions here on the forum is getting more and more complicated. Thanks for publishing my question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it'll work with only one column. Can you post your complete dataframe?

Worked for me with this code:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'index': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
                   'name': ['A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'F']})

    df_pivot = pd.pivot(df, values='name' ,columns='name')
    print(df_pivot)
```

**Output:**

```
name    A    B    C    D    F
0       A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     NaN    B  NaN  NaN  NaN
2     NaN  NaN  NaN    D  NaN
3     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    F
4     NaN  NaN    C  NaN  NaN
5       A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6     NaN    B  NaN  NaN  NaN
7     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    F
```

Comment: Well, many thanks for a good try. The attached table is a fair example representing my use case. I have 4 repetitive features in one column. Those features (name1, name2, ect have different values). So as a result I should arrive at a data frame consisting of 4 columns and two rows in the given example. From that perspective the above clue is somewhat missed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have resolved my case and I am sharing it. It seems that loc and zip functions do the job. If somebody finds a nicer way, please share.

```
out1 = df.loc[1]
out2 = df.loc[3]
out3 = df.loc[5]
out4 = df.loc[7]
final = pd.DataFrame(zip(out1[0], out2[0], out3[0],out4[0]),columns=['name_1', 
'name2','name3', 'name4'])'
```

And finally I have arrived at the output presented above in my question.